# Docker-Selenium Grid 4 with Video recording on Azure Container Instances: Cannot open display error

Tags: azure, docker, selenium-grid, azure-container-instances

Given yaml file `definition.yml` with definition of containers

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: germanywestcentral
name: nameforcontainergroup
properties:
  containers:
  - name: selenium-hub
    properties:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.1-20211217
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1
      environmentVariables:
      - name: SCREEN_WIDTH
        value: "1920"
      - name: SCREEN_HEIGHT
        value: "1080"
      - name: VNC_NO_PASSWORD
        value: 1
      ports:
      - port: 4444
  - name: chrome-node-1-video
    properties:
      image: selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20211217
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 2
      environmentVariables:
      - name: DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME
        value: selenium-hub
      - name: FILE_NAME
        value: chrome-node-video.mp4
      volumeMounts:
      - name: videos
        mountPath: /videos
    
  osType: Linux
  volumes:
  - name: devshm
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: downloads
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: videos
    emptyDir: {}
  ipAddress:    
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '4444'
    type: Public
    dnsNameLabel: some-dns-label
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Assuming group `group-name` exists, to deploy containers run from Azure CLI:
az login
az container create --resource-group group-name --file definition.yml

Containers are deployed, **grid is running but video container cannot connect to grid**

```
Cannot open display selenium-hub:99.0, error 1.
selenium-hub:99.0: Input/output error
```

Full container logs:

```
2021-12-30 09:06:38,504 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2021-12-30 09:06:38,508 INFO supervisord started with pid 31
2021-12-30 09:06:39,511 INFO spawned: 'video-recording' with pid 36
2021-12-30 09:06:39,515 INFO spawned: 'video-ready' with pid 37
Checking if the display is open...
2021-12-30 09:06:39,524 INFO success: video-recording entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2021-12-30 09:06:39,525 INFO success: video-ready entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
Waiting before next display check...
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --enable-shared --enable-avresample --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvidstab --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxcb --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-postproc --enable-small --enable-version3 --enable-libbluray --enable-libzmq --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaom --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-libsrt --enable-libaribb24 --extra-cflags=-I/opt/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/ffmpeg/lib
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[x11grab @ 0x556baa816b80] Cannot open display selenium-hub:99.0, error 1.
selenium-hub:99.0: Input/output error
2021-12-30 09:07:05,243 INFO exited: video-recording (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Have I missed some configuration?

Yaml reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml

Update 1:
Version with hub + node + video-node. Node is registered to hub but video-node fails with exactly the same error as for standalone-node

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: germanywestcentral
name: nameforcontainergroup2
properties:
  containers:
  - name: selenium-hub
    properties:
      image: selenium/hub:4.1.1-20211217
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1
      ports:
      - port: 4444
  - name: chrome-node
    properties:
      image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.1-20211217
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 2
      environmentVariables:
      - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST
        value: localhost
      - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT
        value: 4442
      - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT
        value: 4443
      - name: SE_NODE_PORT
        value: 5560
      - name: VNC_NO_PASSWORD
        value: 1
      volumeMounts:
      - name: devshm
        mountPath: /dev/shm
      - name: downloads
        mountPath: /home/seluser/downloads
  - name: chrome-node-1-video
    properties:
      image: selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20211217
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 2
      environmentVariables:
      - name: DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME
        value: chrome-node
      - name: FILE_NAME
        value: chrome-node_video.mp4
      volumeMounts:
      - name: videos
        mountPath: /videos
    
  osType: Linux
  volumes:
  - name: devshm
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: downloads
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: videos
    emptyDir: {}
  ipAddress:    
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '4444'
    type: Public
    dnsNameLabel: some-dns-label
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the references give an idea to workaround :

Please check if you have missed giving host ,ports like publish port in selenium hub environment variables and using it for chrome.Make sure to open other ports too.
And check if you have properly configured container for selenium hub and chrome and using it for video recording.

```
-name: selenium-node-chrome
image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.1-20211217
....
...
environmentVariables:
- name: SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST
value: selenium-hub
- name: SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT
value: '4442'
- name: SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT
value: '4443'
- name: SE_NODE_HOST
value: node-chrome
- name: SE_NODE_PORT
value: '5555'
```

For Video

```
- name: chrome-node-1-video
....//other properties 
image: selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20211217
.....
environmentVariables:
- name: DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME
value: selenium-node-chrome
- name: FILE_NAME
  value: chrome-node-video.mp4

…..
```

configure selenium-hub

```
-name:selenium-hub
image: selenium/hub:4.1.1-20211217
container_name: selenium-hub
ports:
- "4442:4442"
- "4443:4443"
- "4444:4444"
```

**References:**

1. [docker compose - set environment
   variable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112662/azure-build-pipeline-docker-compose-set-environment-variable)
2. [Chrome Node does not register correctly to the hub -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259711/selenium-4-chrome-node-does-not-register-correctly-to-the-hub)
3. [docker-compose-v3-video.yml at trunk ·(github.com)](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3-video.yml)
4. [Error:cannot open display: :99 in Jenkins Ubuntu - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219336/cannot-open-firefox-browser-selenium-automation-script-error-cannot-open-disp)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately I haven't found any option which fixed that.

1. option with hub + node + video also does not work (node is registered with hub but video cannot connect to display) I will update question with example yml file

2. Docker-compose - I failed to create grid on Azure using docker-compose - mostly due to the fact the Azure version of docker-compose does not support port mapping